# The ECLIPSE RCP project could not be exported successfully

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I met an error when I exported the Eclipse Product using the export wizard on the overview tab of the .product file , 
the error message is as below . 
but it worked just fine when I ran it from inside of Eclipse as an Eclipse Application.
can anybody provide some idea about this .

```
C:\workSpace\0709\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.pde.core\temp\org.eclipse.pde.container.feature\package.org.eclipse.pde.container.feature.win32.win32.x86_64.xml:90: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\workSpace\0709\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.pde.core\temp\org.eclipse.pde.container.feature\package.org.eclipse.pde.container.feature.win32.win32.x86_64.xml:1140: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\tool\eclipse-standard-kepler-SR2-win32-x86_64\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.pde.build_3.8.100.v20130514-1028\scripts\genericTargets.xml:243: A problem occured while invoking the director.
```

Thanks & Regards,
Jeff

Comment: The first thing to check is that you have included **all** the required plugins / features in the Dependencies in the .product file.

Comment: I think i have included all the required plugins in the Dependencies in .product file . even if including all the plugins under the eclipse plugins folder , the same error will come . very very confused .

Comment: more error info detai:at org.apache.tools.ant.ProjectHelper.addLocationToBuildException(ProjectHelper.java:551)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:444)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.CallTarget.execute(CallTarget.java:105)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)

Comment: Caused by: C:\workSpace\0709\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.pde.core\temp\org.eclipse.pde.container.feature\
package.org.eclipse.pde.container.feature.win32.win32.x86_64.xml:1140: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\tool\eclipse-standard-kepler-SR2-win32-x86_64\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.pde.build_3.8.100.v20130514-1028\
scripts\genericTargets.xml:243: A problem occured while invoking the director.

at org.apache.tools.ant.ProjectHelper.addLocationToBuildException(ProjectHelper.java:551)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:444)

Comment: Caused by: C:\tool\eclipse-standard-kepler-SR2-win32-x86_64\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.pde.build_3.8.100.v20130514-1028\scripts\genericTargets.xml:243:A problem occured while invoking the director.
at org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director.app.ant.DirectorTask.execute(DirectorTask.java:88)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor313.invoke(Unknown Source)

Comment: Looks like an error occurred running the p2 director, possibly something to do with paths.

Comment: thank you reply my question . Maybe this issue is related with the path . but i don't know how to do in the next step :(  . and i opened the genericTargets.xml . find the the line 243 code is like below .

Comment: <p2.director 
  os="${os}" ws="${ws}" arch="${arch}" 
  flavor="${p2.flavor}" 
  roaming="true" 
  profile="${p2.director.profile}"
  extraArguments="${p2.director.extraArgs}"
  metadataRepository="${p2.repo}" 
  artifactRepository="${p2.repo}" 
  destination="${p2.director.installPath}" 
  bundlepool="${p2.director.bundlepool}"
  agentLocation="${p2.director.dataArea}"
  outputProperty="p2.director.java.output"
line 243 logFile="${p2.director.log}">
  <iu id="${p2.director.iu}"   version="${p2.director.version}" />
 </p2.director>

Comment: line 243 logFile="${p2.director.log}"

Answer (score 1):

The originating problem is somewhere else.. To find it out add following line to your genericTargets.xml under node `<target name="runDirector">` -> `<record name="path_to_log_output_file" loglevel="verbose">` . Then you will probably see actual problem.